# Facebook like button error: "Be the first of your friends to like this. · Error"

Tags: facebook, joomla, web, facebook-like

I have a Joomla website and i use Facebook buttons.
Everything worked fine for a while, however in the last month I get the following error when I press on the "like" button:
"Be the first of your friends to like this. · Error"

Does anybody know what is the reason/solution to this problem?

Thanks,
Eyal.

http://reginiano.com/

Comment: What error is displayed when you click the 'error' link?

Comment: The word "Error" is a clickable link to the actual error.  Click it and let us know what it says.

Comment: Hey friends,
The error link led me to: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Freginiano.com%2F

It gives response code 206says 4 "like button" warnings and 4 "open graph" warnings.

Comment: And i'm not sure how to solve the warnings...

Comment: You need to update code.|
Facebook change their code- so you need to do it too.
_Works for me..._